# Extract XML date to PHP

Tags: php, xml, date

I have an XML document with an entry looking like this:

```
<recall-number id="F-2402-2015">
     <product-type>Food</product-type>
     <event-id>70195</event-id>
     <status>Ongoing</status>
     <recalling-firm>Northhampton Peanut Company</recalling-firm>  
     <city>Severn</city>
     <state>NC</state>
     <country>US</country>
     <voluntary-mandated>Voluntary: Firm Initiated</voluntary-mandated>
     <initial-firm-notification>Letter</initial-firm-notification>
     <distribution-pattern>CT, MA, NJ, NY and PA.</distribution-pattern>
     <classification>Class II</classification>  
     <product-quantity>unknown</product-quantity> 
     <reason-for-recall>Undeclared Non-Allergen: Sulfites</reason-for-recall> 
     <recall-initiation-date>12/24/2014</recall-initiation-date>
     <report-date>06/10/2015</report-date>
</recall-number>
```

I'm using simplexml_load_file and am able to obtain all of the fields, however the two date fields at the end (recall-initiation-date/report-date) are showing up blank. After some research I used the date function:

```
function get_recalls() {
     $url = "Enforcement-Reports-Export.xml";
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
     foreach($xml->{'recall-number'} as $product) {
          $recall_initiation_date = date('d/m/Y', $product{'recall-initiation-date'});
          $report_date = date('d/m/Y', $product{'report-date'});

          echo $recall_initiation_date;
          echo $report_date;
     }
}
```

However the date that it returns is 01/01/1970 and not the correct date.

Comment: blank = boolean false, because you fed `date()` the wrong value...

Answer (score 2):

Because `date()` expects a Unix timestamp as a parameter and you are giving it a string. Use `strtotime()` to convert those dates into a Unix timestamp.

```
$recall_initiation_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($product{'recall-initiation-date'}));
$report_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($product{'report-date'}));
```

Comment: Copied and pasted into code, still returns 01/01/1970 as output :(

Comment: echo out $product{'recall-initiation-date'} and make sure you see the proper date

Comment: It doesn't print out anything at all actually. Does that mean that simplexml_load_file can't extract the date? If there's no date supplied, then the date() and strtotime() functions would print out the Jan 1 1970 date by default. So I'm lost.

Comment: Looks like you have  a parsing issue. At a glance your code looks good. do a `var_dump($product)` and see what that shows.

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string 'D-1115-2015' (length=11)
  public 'product-type' => string 'Drugs' (length=5)
  ...
  public 'recall-initiation-date' => string '04/15/2015' (length=10)
  public 'report-date' => string '06/10/2015' (length=10)

Comment: It worked when I added the arrow: $product[0]->{'recall-initiation-date'}

Thank you so much for your help.